# Lizard Racing, How To Train My Lizard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

In Alik'r there is a quest to win a race using a lizard. With the option of 3 lizards, 1 free 2 for gold. Also with the option to buy a treat that is supposed to boost your lizard.

I have tried the free lizard, free lizard plus treat. Bought one of the lizards and a treat for him. I have lost them all with the same result each time. I have tried racing during the day and night, since she says the sand might be to hot, same result.

I am hesitant to try the 3rd lizard as I have already spent between 1-2k gold trying to do this quest. I can't seem to find anything anywhere about this dumb quest.

Edit:

Bought the third lizard and still lost, I have given up till I find a solid answer.

Comment: That sounds similar to the frog racing that we could do in Auridon in beta. In frog racing, the trick was to just get the most expensive frog, feed it, and let it go. Not sure if there was any RNG involved, or not.

Comment: @koviko they are all they same price, or free

Comment: Just for the record, I haven't run into the lizard quest yet, but I did the frog race, and you had to feed the frog, examine it, feed the frog, examine it, etc until during an examination it said "the frog looks full". Not sure what happens if you stop before then, but I waited till my frog was full, and it won.

Comment: Did you solve the quest after a year? :p My answer works, though.

Comment: @Trollwut i haven't play in at least a year, although i do have plans to come back to it in the near future on xbox.

Comment: Be aware that you don't have AddOns on console, which I would really miss! But the game has done pretty well, it's worth checking out! (Especially because since you have an account it's without subscription now.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recently did this quest and this will help:

**1. Don't buy the "normal" lizard**

There is a second merchant who will sell a lizard to you. It's location is a bit south of the "normal" vendor.

[image]

**2. This lizard will still lose. Feed it!**

Now head back to the "normal vendor", who will then feed your lizard to be superior for some additional money.

**3. Win that race!**

Now place your lizard in the box and look how it will win. After that you can claim your prize money, which will unfortunatelly be much less than you expensed. But hey, at least you have finished that quest!

Answer (score -2):

Go up North to Sentinel then return to the woman that you could've gotten the free lizard from and have her feed it. It'll win after that.

Comment: This doesn't add anything that the other answer hasn't already covered.